# ASP.NET how to debug mobile version?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, mobile

I am working with a platform on ASP.net that does not have a native mobile version.

I am tasked with debugging a problem that is only for mobile users however searching the codebase for "mobile" or "useragent" does not return anything meaningful that I can use to reverse engineer to find the root problem. It appears that the only mobile checks on the platform are from jQuery regex checks against the useragent and are very very minimal checks to disable a button and not set any global or local variables.

I have tried using Chrome's Mobile Simulator but it seems that only changes the screen resolution rather than simulate a real mobile device. I have also tried modifying the user agent using browser extensions to no avail.

How can I force my desktop browser to load the mobile version of the website for debugging?
Where does ASP.NET determine the device type at?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem I was experiencing was from the way JQuery UI worked on mobile devices causing code that worked fine on desktop to not work the same way on mobile.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34977576)